# angularFire can't remove data

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am creating a practice application using angularFire to integrate Angular.js with firebase. So far, I am able to pull down data, display it, and add to it. But for some reason I can't delete existing data. I've added a button that uses ng-click to point to removeProject, and when clicked, the entry will disappear from the list, but if the page is refreshed, the entry reappears as if it had never been deleted. I've tried this locally and hosted externally and both have the same results.

Here is the working code that adds entries:

```
$scope.addProject = function() {
    $scope.projects.add({name: $scope.newName, status: $scope.newStatus});
    $scope.newName = "";
    $scope.newStatus = "";
};
```

And here is the broken code the should remove entries:

```
$scope.removeProject = function(project) {
    $scope.projects.splice($scope.projects.indexOf(project), 1);
};
```

I took this pattern from the todo example, just changing the names, yet it's not working.

Comment: I was actually able to fix this myself. I forgot to wrap these in a .then()

Comment: Cool! Could you answer your question so it will benefit others who might have the same problem? :)